# Каково происхождение слова "положительный"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

**Положение — положительный, позиция — позитивный?** Но откуда следует все указанные ниже  значения, почему они связаны с положением?

Есть ли среди них **главное (центральное)** значение, из которого следуют остальные?

1. **Выражающий согласие; утвердительный**. Положительный ответ.
2. **Обладающий нужными свойствами,**  заслуживающий одобрения, оправдывающий ожидания. Положительные результаты. Положительный пример.
3. **Деловой, деловитый, практический.**   Для этой женщины со здоровым, положительным умом ...
4. **Определенный, окончательный.**   ... он  получил от Алексея Александровича положительный отказ в разводе Анны.

Нашла **у Фасмера:**

позити́вный

"положительный, определенный", начиная с Петра I; см. Смирнов 229. Через нем. positiv "определенный" (с 1652 г.; см. Шульц–Баслер 2, 610 и сл.) или франц. positif из лат. positīvus.

Но **positīvus** — это положительный.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ  (о положительных зарядах)**

1) По теории Франклина, сформулированной им в 1747 г.тело наэлектризовано либо потому, что у него имеется **избыток** **электрического флюида** по сравнению с нормальным состоянием, либо потому, что у него оказывается меньше электрического флюида, нежели в нормальном состоянии.

В первом случае Франклин называет тело положительно (плюс), во втором - отрицательно (минус) электризованным. Эта терминология сохранилась до наших дней.

2) Плюс (лат. plus «больше» — сравнительная степень от лат. multum «много») — графический **символ операции сложения**.

3) Остается считать,что прибыль (увеличение) — это знак одобрения, обозначающий  положительное явление.

4) Но тогда все равно мы возвращаемся к основному значению слова:  положительный — это имеющий основание, надежный, хороший, правильный.

Comment: мои догадки, возможно есть связь со словами "пологий" и "покладистый", т.е. нечто, не оказывающее сопротивления, наклонное, склонное, в то время как слово "отрицательный" содержит по-видимому корень -рек-, т.е. нечто перечащее, несогласное, прекословное, в русском есть также слово "располагающий" (однокоренное с "пологий") семантически родственное слову positio через "положение"

Comment: Wiktionary утверждает, что это действительно калька с латыни, но так ли она была влиятельна на Руси? может быть через французский?

Answer (score 3):

**Положительный** действительно от слова "положение", только это **прилагательное** вошло в русский язык не в давнее время, а, видимо, всё-таки во времена Петра 1, когда появились математические термины и слово "позиция". **Позитивный** - от **позиция**. В современном слове "положение" объединились др.-р. **положение** -"размещение" (отмечается в памятниках письменности с 11 века как "размещение", "погребение", "изложение") и фр.калька.

https://etymological.academic.ru/3851

Позиция - Заимств. в Петровскую эпоху через польск. посредство из франц. яз., в котором position < лат. positio «положение», суф. производного от ponere «класть, располагать, ставить».
Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва. 2004.

Основное значение слова **положительный** всё-таки "больше нуля, со знаком плюс". Вспомним историю положительных и отрицательных чисел.
Положительное число долго трактовалось как «прибыль», а отрицательное – как «убыток», «долг». Знака «плюс» и «минус» в древности не знали ни для числа, ни для действий. Греческий математик Диофант Александрийский обозначал вычитание стрелочкой. В Италии ростовщики, давая деньги в долг, ставили перед именем должника сумму долга и чёрточку, вроде нашего минуса, а когда должник возвращал деньги, зачёркивали. Получалось что-то вроде нашего плюса.   В 1544 году немецкий математик Михаил Штифель впервые рассматривает отрицательные числа как числа, меньшие нуля (т. е. « меньшие, чем ничто »). С этого момента отрицательные числа рассматриваются уже не как долг, а совсем по-новому. Сам Штифель писал: «Нуль находится между   истинными и абсурдными числами…».  В 1637 г. французский математик, физик и философ Ренё Декарт предложил геометрическое истолкование положительных и отрицательных чисел – ввел координатную прямую. Всё, что больше нуля, - положительные, истинные, реальные числа и действия, всё, что меньше, - отрицательные,  абсурдные, ирреальные (нереальные)

Отсюда **положительный ответ** - со знаком плюс: "Да, это имеется, реально", "Не отрицаю", "Утверждаю".

Положительный пример, результат (позитивный) - занимающий положительную, реальную позицию, а значит, обладающий нужными свойствами, заслуживающий одобрения, оправдывающий ожидания.

Положительный, практический ум - без фантазий, ирреальных выдумок, т.е. без всяких глупостей, признаёт то, что реально важно для человека, а для него реальна прибыль.

Определенный, окончательный. (*... он получил от Алексея Александровича положительный отказ в разводе Анны*.) - отголосок значения **положение - указ, закон**, т.е. закреплённый положением, указом, не исполнить нельзя.

Comment: Я всё-таки думаю, что центральное значение слова - это имеющий основание, определенное положение, позицию. Это, безусловно,  самое важное и ценное качество. Что касается чисел, то это надо смотреть историю названий, но в принципе можно исходить из того, что положительные заряды находятся в  неподвижном ядре (это как бы основная часть атома, определяющая его массу), а отрицательные электроны вращаются вокруг (согласно планетарной модели).

Comment: Ну, это каждый по-своему думает, вот только с зарядами - слишком мудрено для обычного человека и бытового употребления слова. Позиция - да, об этом я и говорю: позиция после нуля, со знаком плюс.   Плюс - принято, прибыль, как в старину считали.

Comment: .Про заряды - да, там другая история, я о ней написала в дополнении к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Есть слово ложе - то, на что можно прилечь, положиться, опереться. "Лоно" - место, где лежит плод, является некой основой, началом жизни. На мой взгляд, корни слова "положительный"  следует искать здесь.

Comment: Возможно, положительный - это имеющий основание, на которое предмет можно положить. Сравнить: обосновать, обоснованный. Отсюда следует определенность (определенная позиция), которая рассматривается как ценное, нужное качество.